# How to prioritize a record In sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to try to write a query. I need to take the Targetvalue from `#MetricTargets` table for the MetricID's which are there in `#Metrics`.

```
{
CREATE TABLE #Metrics(
MetricId BiginT,
AccountId Bigint,
CountryId Bigint
)

INSERT INTO #Metrics(MetricId,AccountId,CountryId)select 8253,3,105

Create table #MetricTargets(
AccountId BIGINT,
MetricId BIGINT,
TargetValue BIGINT,
Countryid BIGINT
)

INSERT  INTO #MetricTargets(AccountId,TargetValue,MetricId,Countryid)SELECT 105,100,3,8253
INSERT  INTO #MetricTargets(AccountId,TargetValue,MetricId,Countryid)SELECT -1,80,3,8253
INSERT  INTO #MetricTargets(AccountId,TargetValue,MetricId,Countryid)SELECT 105,99,-1,8253 
}
```

CountryId=-1 and AccountId =-1 represents for all Countries and Accounts

So I want to retrieve Targetvalue for a metricId if the AccountId and CountryId is given in `#MetricTargets` table in first Priority , AccountId =Something and countryId = -1 is 2 nd priority,ACcountId=-1 and CountryId= SomeThing then 3rd priority and AccountId =-1 and CountryId=-1 then last priority.

I wrote the below query but it is giving all records.

```
select M.TargetValue from #Metrics S   
LEFT JOIN #MetricsTargets M
ON  M.MetricId = S.MetricId AND (S.AccountId+M.AccountId<S.AccountId or S.AccountId = M.AccountId)
                               AND (S.CountryId+M.CountryId<S.CountryId or S.CountryId=M.CountryId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want matching with `-1` as a wildcard of lower priority.  I'm pretty sure a lateral join does what you want:

```
select . . . 
from #Metrics m OUTER APPLY
     (select top (1) mt.*
      from #MetricsTargets mt
      where mt.MetricId = m.MetricId and
            m.account_id in (mt.account_id, -1) and
            m.country_id in (mt.country_id, -1)
      order by (case when mt.account_id = m.account_id and mt.country_id = m.country_id
                     then 1
                     when mt.account_id = m.account_id and mt.country_id = -1
                     then 2
                     when mt.account_id = -1 and mt.country_id = m.country_id
                     then 3
                     when mt.account_id = -1 and mt.country_id = -1
                     then 4
                end)
     ) mt
```

Comment: But from #Metrics, we get only AccountId<>-1  and CountryId<>-1 only whats point in pointing  M.accountid in(mt.AccountId,-1) and you have kept Alias name as #MetricTargets t and used mt in subquery...I'm bit confused